# pagination in html page is not correctly showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

hi i am try implement pagination in my mvc cshtml page..

i have total number of rows and count(each page contain 10 rows) and i am using the following loop and bootstrap css for this

```
       <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
            @for (pcount = 1; pcount <= (tot / c); pcount++)
            {
                <li><a href="~/Log/Index?p=@pcount">@pcount</a></li>
            }
            <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>
```

i got the output like

[image]

it shows all the pages..(i want to shoe only 3 pages and other pages are only shown when next or previous button pressed.)is there any jquery for that..
one more doubt if my total is 123 it shows 12 pages. i want to show 13 pages.. how can i rearrage my loop.

Comment: Try this [plugin](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) it should fit your requirement

Comment: i cant use plugin.. thats why i am asking this question

Comment: ahh you said - is there any jquery for that.. I don't think that would be handy you may end up writing something that is defined in this plugin take a look and write your own using simple jquery.